# ApiAiClient request to Dialogflow API fails in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialogflow-es, spfx, api-ai

I use React and SPFX, when I try to connect to the Dialogflow API it fails in IE. It works in other browsers(Chrome, Edge, Firefox).

```
import { ApiAiClient } from 'api-ai-javascript';

var accessToken = "...";
var client = new ApiAiClient({accessToken});
```

'new ApiAiClient()' does not work in IE? Because of this problem my webpart in SharePoint won't load at all.

[I'm getting this error in the IE console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDXF8.png)

Comment: By any chance. Have you solved this.